# What's the easiest (quickest) way to share one dataset in my app with someone else

Tags: database, frameworks, persistence

I have some javascript that creates a canvas image that I want users to be able to share. I simply need to save the image somehow. Nothing else.

I've been contemplating using bits and pieces of ruby and activerecord, or perhaps sinatra but I feel like both would be over kill for this simple task.

Ideally I'd like to do it with JavaScript but I don't feel like including all of node. Any suggestions?

Comment: Depends on the database. Some come with commandline tools that would allow to execute SQL from a bash script. Otherwise Ruby with ActiveRecord (no Rails needed) would be just a few lines of code. Do you want to save the image itself or a path/reference to the image?

Comment: @thorstenmüller the database can be anything. I want to save the image and generate a URL that the user can share. Those are really the only requirements.

Comment: Any security features needed or are you going to share the file with all the users?

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way? HTTP POST/PUT the image to a server that saves it on the disk (no DB) and gives it back on a GET to it's url. The server code should be trivial in whatever language you chose.

Maybe you can do this without any server code at all if you can use a webserver (Apache etc.) that supports this scenario. [WebDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) publishing comes to mind

Comment: +1, this is about as straight forward as it gets.  If the number of files gets large, at that point a db might be useful to track them, to make it easier to expire older files.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to share something that lives clientside in your browser, you can always access querystring arguments with JavaScript and use that as the input, and have the javascript display a URL string that would recreate the live image.

The data required to recreate the image may be significant depending on the complexity and your approach (I would suggest some vector data as opposed to any actual scrape from the canvas, but you'd have to tell more about how you are drawing stuff on the canvas), and because of the size this may mean the querystring is horribly large. All the same this should work; post your webpage of HTML/JavaScript to a website and if people put the querystring url you give them, the webpage's JavaScript can parse that and recreate the canvas from the data in it.

This would get you away from doing any server side work if you really don't know anything about server side coding and don't want to kick up a server.